# How to access latitude and longitude data from the page source of a craigslist search?

Tags: html, r

So I have been trying to pull latitude and longitude data from the page source of a craigslist search, but I can't seem to find the data. I am basically trying to replicate another example that I found on Stack Overflow, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279254/webscraping-with-r-and-the-xml-package)

The problem I seem to be having is that, unlike in the example from the link above, I cannot find these data in the source `<p`, although `<div` contains `id="mapcontainer"`, `data-arealat`, and `data-arealon`.

I am using the following function to pull the attributes that I want:

```
xpathSApply(X,path="//p[@attribute I want]",fun = xmlGetAttr , name = 'name of attribute')
```

The problem is that I cannot find any latitude and longitude data in the page source. My question, then, is whether there is some sort of conversion from other attributes which must be done to get latitude and longitude data for each listing of a craigslist search?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which url interests you? http://chicago.craigslist.org/search/apa?query=pilsen&zoomToPosting=&srchType=A&minAsk=&maxAsk=&bedrooms=&housing_type= is invalid.

Comment: Actually, a specific url does not interest me. The link I provided is just to show that the solution to the question asked there is the method that I have explored so far. My issue is that, given any search I try in craigslist, I cannot find the latitude and longitude attributes of the listings.